# What are the white spots and holes in the leaves of my Western Indian Lime Tree?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, insects

Do you have any ideas about why my there are white spots and holes in the leaves of my Lime Tree? What might the pest be and how can I rectify this? Any products you recommend? I live in Melbourne and it's generally a temperate climate.

[image] 
[image]

---

Here are more pictures of the tree, hopefully this will help more (sorry, issue with posting several pictures, blame on J. Chomel)

[image] 
 [image]

Comment: You have possibly more than one insect here...as well as possibly some chemical damage.  What have you been doing for fertilizer and could you send closeups of the undersides of the leaves?  Clean all debris from the base of your tree a good 3' diameter.

Comment: Hi @stormy! 10 rep is needed to post more than two pictures. It's set up by the system, so the only way around it is to upvote the question!

Comment: Thought I did that...how about replacing or being able to do side by side?  This rule DOES NOT  MAKE SENSE.  Sigh.

Comment: @stormy Replacing works, but there can only still be two, so where OP puts them doesn't matter. I see the upvote now, so everything's all set. Thanks for helping our new member!

Answer (score 2):

Your tree suffered quite extended insect or bird damage, but it look very very healthy. The insects or enemies seem to be gone now. It's healed.

There is nothing I would do. Perhaps just pick its fruits: if you want to remove stress and optimize the tree's growth for next year.

Do not overuse chemicals and pesticides in your yard. Leave this to nature enemies. If you do, you risk to cause more imbalance for the years to come, and need more pesticides - set aside the damage you'll cause to all the natural life.